# No self parameter passed in overrided python class' method

Tags: python, function, class

Take a look at this code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 'Hello, World!'

    def func(self):
        return self._value

instance = SomeClass()

print(instance.func())

def new_func(self):
    return self._value + '!!!!!'

instance.func = new_func

print(instance.func())
```

This code creates an instance of `SomeClass`, calls original `func`, then overrides this function and calls it again.
I want to override a function in a single instance of a class, but not in the entire class so all the instances got the function overrided.
I expect this code to print:

```
Hello, World!
Hello, World!!!!!
```

But it prints:

```
Hello, World!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(instance.func())
TypeError: new_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The `self` argument is not passed to the overrided function. Why? Aren't `SomeClass.func(instance)` and `instance.func()` the same?

How to override the function correctly so I can access the `self` argument in the overrided function?

Comment: `new_func` isn't actually a method; it's just an ordinary instance attribute, whose value happens to be a function.  The magic that adds the `self` parameter only happens when a function is retrieved from the *class*; see "descriptor protocol" for the details.  You could do `instance.func = lambda: new_func(instance)` or `instance.func = functools.partial(new_func, instance)` to supply the `self` value yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's see

The `func` of the original instance has type `bound method`

```
SomeClass().func

# <bound method SomeClass.func of <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7f293e1cb3d0>>
```

and your `func` has type `function`

```
instance.func

# <function __main__.new_func(self)>
```

The idea is to get a new method of some new class like this:

```
class SomeNewClass:
    def new_func(self):
        return self._value + '!!!!!'

instance.func = SomeNewClass().new_func
instance.func

# <bound method SomeNewClass.new_func of <__main__.SomeNewClass object at 0x7f293e2825d0>>
```

But as you see, this is a method of the new class :(

By the way, if you don't initialize the class, the type will change to `function`:

```
class SomeNewClass:
    def new_func(self):
        return self._value + '!!!!!'

instance.func = SomeNewClass.new_func
instance.func

# <function __main__.SomeNewClass.new_func(self)>
```

So the next idea is to change the method before the initialization of a class:

```
SomeClass.func = new_func
instance = SomeClass()
instance.func

# <bound method new_func of <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7f29441e4350>>
```

Seems good. The result based on your code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 'Hello, World!'

    def func(self):
        return self._value

instance = SomeClass()

print(instance.func())

def new_func(self):
    return self._value + '!!!!!'

SomeClass.func = new_func
instance = SomeClass()

print(instance.func())

# Hello, World!
# Hello, World!!!!!!
```

If you need to change the method of an instance and not of the class. There is also a way to do that using `types.MethodType`:

```
import types

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 'Hello, World!'

    def func(self):
        return self._value

instance = SomeClass()

print(instance.func())

def new_func(self):
    return self._value + '!!!!!'

instance.func = types.MethodType(new_func, instance)

print(instance.func())

# Hello, World!
# Hello, World!!!!!!
```